# res.render ONLY after multiple data queries have finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

On my app.get in my server.js, I am returning a data set from mongo db, and then rendering my page whilst passing the data to it.

**as shown bellow:**

```
//page load
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    //find all data in test table
    var articles;
    db.collection('test').find().toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        articles = result

            // renders index.ejs and passes result to quotes
        res.render('./pages/index.ejs', {
            quotes: articles
        })
    })
})
```

I want to be able to put multiple db queries, and then pass multiple variables of data to my render, my problem is that when I put my res.render outside of a db query, it tries to render before the db gets its data set.

**see what I tried bellow:**

```
//page load
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    //find all data in test table
    var articles;
    db.collection('test').find().toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        articles = result
    })

        // renders index.ejs and passes result to quotes
        res.render('./pages/index.ejs', {
            quotes: articles
        })
})
```

**my question is:**

How could I make sure that the render happens **ONLY** after my db queries have run and returned the data to a variable?

---

> Ultimately I would want to be able to do something like this:

```
//page load
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    //find all data in table 1
    var AAA;
    db.collection('test1').find().toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        AAA = result
    })

     //find all data in table 2
    var BBB;
    db.collection('test2').find().toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        BBB = result
    })

     //find all data in table 3
    var CCC;
    db.collection('test3').find().toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        CCC = result
    })

        // renders index.ejs and passes result to quotes
        res.render('./pages/index.ejs', {
            quotes: AAA,
            quotes2: BBB,
            quotes3: CCC
        })
})
```

Any help or advice on this is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're using native mongodb client, then don't pass callbacks, so it returns promise, then just use `then`, perform a query, assign the result to an external variable, then another `then`, perform a query and so on.

Comment: the first query would be ideal, but I would want to be able to do multiple queries and then pass all the results into the render at the end, see edit. @jstice4all

Comment: I have edited my comment.

Comment: ahh i see, how would I implement that within my code? @jstice4all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code, it's not tested but I think it should work:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    var list = {};

    db.collection('test').find().toArray().then(result => {
        list.result = result;
    }).then(() => {
        return Promise.resolve(db.collection('foo').find().toArray());
    }).then(result2 => {
        list.result2 = result2;
    }).then(() => {
        return Promise.resolve(db.collection('bar').find().toArray());
    }).then(result3 => {
        list.result3 = result3;
    }).then(() => {
        res.render('./pages/index.ejs', list);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
    });

});
```

Update: we can use async/await for any method that returns Promise so the code would be cleaner:

```
// you can use express-async-errors package to make routes async
app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    let list = [];
    list.result = await db.collection('test').find().toArray();
    list.result2 = await db.collection('foo').find().toArray();
    list.result3 = await db.collection('bar').find().toArray();
    res.render('./pages/index.ejs', list);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `async` module for that. Use `async.parallel` for functions which are independant of each other and use `async.series` for dependent processes. Check [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).